# Visual Studio 2017 HRESULT: 0x80004004

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I was perfectly running an ASP.NET Core project in a docker container, but then I created another project in the same solution, which was referenced by the first one.
When building, VS 2017 didn't complain. When debugging, VS says:
"Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))"
Then I tried creating a new solution with new project **(Only one this time)**. Same thing happened: Build successfull, debugging - impossible. Restarting computer did't work, neither VS with admin privilages.

How can I fix that? I am ready to screw the whole project and start all over, if needed. I appriciate any response. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed it with these simpler steps ;)

1. Reset Shared Drives in Docker for Windows. (Re-entering your credentials if needed by using the reset credentials link)
2. Clean your VS solution and rebuild
3. Debug

Comment: Simple, worked perfectly, `Docker 17.06.2-ce` and `Visual Studio 2017  15.3.3`.

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the directory : **%userprofile%\vsdbg**, it worked to me.

Comment: This did it for me as well.

Comment: This works, but beware that after deleting the vsdbg folder, VS will download the debugger again and in my case the process was really slow (other people experienced the same slow download, checked other threads and the official Microsoft Forums), some of them suggest to download the debugger manually and uncompress it on the deleted folder.

Answer (score 1):

Check the folder in your windows ~\vsdbg
Probably are missing the correct files.

This occours because you didn't execute the add docker support in your current instance of visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem that caused this error for me was that I was originally running Windows 10 Home Edition and some residual settings from that were causing the error.

Solution:

1. Uninstall Docker for Windows
2. Uninstall all versions of Visual Studio
3. Delete all settings folders for Visual Studio in %UserProfile%, %ProgramData%, and %AppData%
4. Upgrade to Windows 10 Pro (Windows Button >> Settings >> Update & Security >> Activation >> Change product key and enter a Windows 10 Pro key if you own one OR purchase an upgrade to Windows 10 Pro with the instructions on the same screen)
5. Install Visual Studio 2017 Professional
6. Install Docker for Windows

Summary:

Even though I upgraded to Windows 10 Pro, enabled Hyper-V and containers, and installed Docker for Windows, Visual Studio 2017 still thought I was on Windows 10 Home and my docker project wouldn't build or load. With some tweaks I still got the error mentioned in the question. Following the steps above I was able to solve the problem.

Comment: I am on Windows 10 Pro

Comment: I posted an alternate solution since the other answers didn't work for me and I think others might benefit from knowing another possible solution.